# how to compile FFMPEG and merge it to one android ".so" file

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg

i am intereseted to compile the ffmpeg source to android to be invoked with jni as one ".so" last time i tried 0.8 versions but failed it always shows that something is undeclared, i tried all of google examples but it seems doesnt work for me, 
i tried this one

[Link One](http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.co.id/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html)

but it seems that the ffmpeg.c is not included with compile , but when i compile it always error, it says that something undeclared, and i cant build this project as one android ".so" file

i also tried this one,
[Link Two](https://hiko.im/posts/zh/2016/01/Android_JNIshiyongffmpeg2_8_4jinxingshipinyasuo_tech.html)

but it seems i cant understand.

i have tried everything , but none of them work ,none of them merge all ".o" , ".so" , ".a" into one ".so" files

is there any good example in google or somewhere to compile ffmpeg as one ".so" file and have a  good downloadable source i can compile?

Comment: _"it says that something undeclared"_ is not a useful problem description. You need to inlcude the _exact_ error messages in your question. And you should also include the make files / commands directly in your question, not just linking to some tutorial.

Comment: @Michael  Did you resolve this? I am looking for the exact same solution.